# jQuery Multiple Grouped Stylesheet Switcher

Tags: jquery

I have three groups of css style sheets and I want to choose one from each group all the time. Looking for some jQuery that does the job, with smooth transition and that the page does not refresh.

Here are the three groups:

1. To choose colors- one of three needs to be active.
2. To choose either header or footer- one of two needs to be active.
3. To choose width of sidebar- one of two needs to be active.

Stylesheets in one group can be chosen irrespective of what stylesheet is active in other two groups.

```
<!--To Choose Colors-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grey.css" title="tgrey">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="green.css" title="tgreen">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navy.css" title="tnavy">

<!--To Choose either header or footer-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="topbar.css" title="ttop">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bottombar.css" title="tbottom">

<!--To Choose normal or wide sidebar-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smallsidebar.css" title="tsmall">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bigsidebar.css" title="tbig">
```

*Thanks*

Comment: Why would you tag this as jQuery?

Comment: @MichielReyers It's in the title, now added that in post. I am looking for jquery styleswitcher,thats why. should I tag it as CSS instead?

Comment: You can add up to 5 tags, so `css` would definitely be a helpful tag.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

In this example, I only used 2 stylesheets to switch between, but if it works for your situation, you can extrapolate.

I added a class `color` to two stylesheets [similar to what you will need]:

```
<link class="color" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="green.css" title="green">
<link class="color" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="red.css" title="red">
```

Where each stylesheet only changes one div's `background-color`. [red.css to 'red', green.css to 'green'].

The function waits for a click anywhere in the HTML `body`:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    function newSheet(className, color) {
        var nodeList = $('link.' + className);
        for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
            nodeList[i].disabled = true;
            if (nodeList[i].title === color) {
                nodeList[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    $('body').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut( function() {
            newSheet('color', 'red');
            $( this ).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

If this works for you and you want help extrapolating to the 2 other 'classes' of stylesheets you need, let me know!